# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework/Multiple Select Statements to retrieve records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

SQL Server Profiler is showing that there are multiple select statements being issued for each record. Is there a way where one SQL statement is issued for all?

```
public override IEnumerable<Person> Get()
{
    return Context.PersonSet.ToList();
}
```

Yields

```
Select * from dbo.Table where PersonId=1
Select * from dbo.Table where PersonId=2
etc..
```

I want it to just issue

```
select * from dbo.Table
```

Comment: I doubt that it'll generate `select` for each id. Please check again

Comment: Is that the actual implementation of your `Get()` method? If so, you should consider rewriting it. Calling `ToList()` will cause all rows in the table to be pulled into memory. It would be better to either apply a filter before calling `ToList()` or have the method return an `IQueryable<Person>` so that filtering may be done by subsequent code and therefore reduce the number of rows returned from the database.

Comment: What is Person model? Maybe Person has some another entities? In that case there foreach Person EF select related entity.